# Restoring Virtualmin backup fails: "Cannot change ownership"

Tags: domain-name-system, backup, restore

I'm attempting to restore my DNS settings from a virtualmin backup after reinstalling bind9.  I've selected only the DNS to be restored, as per the advice in [this link,](http://readlist.com/lists/lists.sourceforge.net/webadmin-list/1/8577.html) regarding duplication of directories exceeding capacity.  However, when I go for it, I'm confronted with the following:

```
Starting restore of 1 domains from local file /home/name/2013-12-04_12.00/mysite.com.tar.gz ..

Extracting backup archive file ..
.. extraction of /home/name/2013-12-04_12.00/mysite.com.tar.gz failed :

/bin/tar: ./.backup/upsmart.com_web_alog: Cannot change ownership to uid 1003, gid 33: Disk quota exceeded
/bin/tar: ./.backup/upsmart.com_web_elog: Cannot change ownership to uid 1003, gid 33: Disk quota exceeded
/bin/tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors

.. failed! See the progress output above for the reason why.
```

Any ideas as to what might be going wrong?

Any input would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Disk quota exceeded` <-- that would be a good starting point for your investigation.

Someone (the user with UID 1003) is over their disk quota.
Your system won't let that user have any more disk space, so you can't extract the backup data to restore it.

Either adjust the user's disk quota (see your operating system's manual, or the Virtualmin documentation for instructions), or delete some of their files so they have enough room within their disk quota to extract the backup.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply!  I wasn't aware that I'd set any quotas for any of the users and I haven't been using any more than 1/4 of the hd at any one time.  How might I be able to see what quotas are set for a given user on a linux system?  Thanks again.

Comment: @neanderslob `(see your operating system's manual, or the Virtualmin documentation for instructions)` <-- c'mon now, you gotta do some of the work too. [`man quota`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/quota), or Google `Virtualmin "check disk quota"` if you want to do it from within Virtualmin...

Comment: "man quota" was actually what I was looking for. I'm sufficiently ignorant of quotas that I really didn't have any idea that there was such a command that was relevant to what I needed.  Anyway, I ended up doing an edquota, increased the limit by an order of magnitude and that did the trick.

Comment: @neanderslob depending on your environment/architecture you may just want to remove the user's quota entirely -- with the exception of shared hosting systems I very rarely enforce quotas anymore because disk is cheap and plentiful.

Comment: I was sort of thinking that.  I don't really know why they were there in the first place; I think they were added under someone else's watch.  I think I'll take that advice.